# How do I read this list and parse it?

Tags: python, list

I'm using requests and the output I get from the sites API is a list, I've been stuck trying to parse it to get the data from it. I use

```
r = requests.get(urlas, params=params)
r.json()
```

to get the data I want.

Here is a snippet of the list `[{'relation_type': None, 'airing_status': 'finished airing', 'popularity': 2354}]`

What I want to do is get the data such as `popularity` or `airing_status` and get it's information such as `2354` and `finished airing`

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: `l[0]['popularity']`

Comment: I see, thank you, I searched a lot of questions but didn't see an answer like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your list contains one dictionary
you can access the data inside like this :

```
>>> yourlist[0]["popularity"]
2354
```

`[0]` for the first item in the list (the dictionary).

`["popularity"]` to get the value associated to the key 'popularity' in the dictionary.